# How to pull email address and password from text file with CMD?

Tags: batch, cmd.exe

**I have a text file named `file.txt` Which contains,**

```
Combo: testing123mail@gmail.com:password
As Combo: 
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@gmail.com:ajfbdf
some text here
some more text here
As Combo: hadvsfhia@ahfjbadj.com:password@1
some random text here
iloveu@gmail.com:passypassyword123
goldenmammy@hotmail.com:youtube123
```

**I am running the below code, to filter only `mail:pass` from the above text file `file.txt`**

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('type file.txt^|find "As Combo:"') do >>mail.txt echo %%a
for /f "tokens=2" %%b in ('type file.txt^|find "Combo:"') do >>mail.txt echo %%b
for /f "tokens=1" %%c in ('type file.txt^|find ":"') do >>mail.txt echo %%c
```

**Expected Output in `mail.txt`,**

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@gmail.com:ajfbdf
hadvsfhia@ahfjbadj.com:password@1
testing123mail@gmail.com:password
iloveu@gmail.com:passypassyword123
goldenmammy@hotmail.com:youtube123
```

**But, am getting actual output is,**

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@gmail.com:ajfbdf
hadvsfhia@ahfjbadj.com:password@1
testing123mail@gmail.com:password
Combo:
Combo:
Combo:
As
As
iloveu@gmail.com:passypassyword123
goldenmammy@hotmail.com:youtube123
```

**Note:** The mail id and passwords will be differ in different text file. Above given mail id and passwords are typed by me randomly for example.

***Kindly fix my code and help to get expected output. Thanks in advance.***

Comment: please someone help :(

Comment: I'm not a batch expert, but if you want, I can help you it with a single line in powershell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this loop with find conditioned by delimiters and tokens...

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "_log=.\mail.txt" && cmd /v /c cd.>!_log!

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%i in ('type .\file.txt')do echo/%%~i|find "@" >nul && (
   for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=:" %%I in ('echo/%%~i')do echo/%%~I|find "@" >nul && (
    set "_m_p=%%~I:%%~J")||set "_m_p=%%~J:%%~K")&& for %%E in ("%%~J")do >>!_log! (
      echo/!_m_p: =!|find "@")
```

> - **Update** - ***Version inspired by the***  <kbd>****`@somebadhat's`****</kbd>  **answer post**
>
>   ---

```bat
@rem.^
                Combo: testing123mail@gmail.com:password^
                As Combo:^
                abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@gmail.com:ajfbdf^
                some text here^
                some more text here^
                As Combo: hadvsfhia@ahfjbadj.com:password@1^
                some random text here^
                iloveu@gmail.com:passypassyword123^
                goldenmammy@hotmail.com:youtube123

@echo off & type nul >.\mail.txt & for /f "tokens=*delims=" %%i in ('type file.txt')do (
echo=%%~i|find "@">nul && for /f "tokens=01,02,03delims=:" %%I in ('call echo=%%~i')do (
echo=%%~I|find "@">nul && set "_m_p=%%I:%%J" || set "_m_p=%%~J:%%~K") && for /f %%E in ('
echo=%%~J')do cmd /v/c "echo=!_m_p: =!"|find "@")>>.\mail.txt ||>nul call nul 2>nul 2>&1
```

---

Comment: I liked your answer so I played around with [it](https://superuser.com/a/1500904/1003800)

Comment: give me an example of mixed style

Comment: Your code works.  The only improvement you could make to your answer is to explain the logic of the commands.  Why is the space in `!_m_p: =!` so important?  I updated my answer.

Comment: `REM` is better than `::`.  You will get less failure if you use `REM`

Answer (score 1):

There is not much new here.  This is how I would have written **It Wasn't Me**'s answer.

```
@REM Win10 64-bit Pull email address:password from text file using CMD: 
@REM Combo: testing123mail@gmail.com:password
@REM some text here 
@REM As Combo: hadvsfhia@ahfjbadj.com:password@1
@REM goldenmammy@hotmail.com:youtube123
@echo off 
cd.> mail.txt
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%i in ('type file.txt') do echo %%~i | find "@" >nul && (
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=:" %%I in ('echo %%~i') do echo %%~I | find "@" >nul && (
set "_m_p=%%I:%%J") || set "_m_p=%%J:%%K") && (
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%E in ("%%J") do echo !_m_p: =! | find "@">> mail.txt 
)
exit /b
```

Or:

```
@echo off & cd.> mail.txt & for /f "tokens=*delims=" %%i in ('type file.txt')do (
echo %%~i|find "@">nul && for /f "tokens=1-3delims=:" %%I in ('echo %%~i')do (
echo %%~I|find "@">nul && set "_m_p=%%I:%%J" || set "_m_p=%%~J:%%~K") && for /f %%E in ('
echo %%~J')do cmd /v/c echo !_m_p: =!|find "@")>> mail.txt
```